# Best way to for C++ types to self register in a list?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some per-class data: (AandB.h)

```
class A
{
public:
   static Persister* getPersister();
}

class B
{
public:
   static Persister* getPersister();
}
```

... and lots and lots more classes. And I want to do something like:

```
persistenceSystem::registerPersistableType( A::getPersister() );
persistenceSystem::registerPersistableType( B::getPersister() );
...
persistenceSystem::registerPersistableType( Z::getPersister() );
```

... for each class.

My question is: is there a way to automate building a list of per-type data so that I don't have to enumerate each type in a big chunk (as in the above example)?

For example, one way you might do this is: (AutoRegister.h)

```
struct AutoRegisterBase
{
   virtual ~AutoRegisterBase() {}
   virtual void registerPersist() = 0;
   static AutoRegisterBase*& getHead()
   {
      static AutoRegisterBase* head= NULL;
      return head;
   }

   AutoRegisterBase* next;
};

template <typename T>
struct AutoRegister : public AutoRegisterBase
{
   AutoRegister() { next = getHead(); getHead() = this; }

   virtual void registerPersist()
   {
       persistenceSystem::registerPersistableType( T::getPersister() );
   }
};
```

and use this as follows:  (AandB.cxx: )

```
static AutoRegister<A> auto_a;
static AutoRegister<B> auto_b;
```

Now, after my program starts, I can safely do: (main.cxx)

```
int main( int, char ** )
{
    AutoRegisterBase* p = getHead();
    while ( p )
    {
        p->registerPersist();
        p = p->next;
    }
    ...
}
```

to collect each piece of per-type data and register them all in a big list somewhere for devious later uses.

The problem with this approach is that requires me to add an AutoRegister object somewhere per type. (i.e. its not very automatic and is easy to forget to do). And what about template classes? What I'd really like is for the instantiation of a template class to somehow cause that class to get automatically registered in the list. If I could do this I would avoid having to have the user of the class (rather than the author) to remember to create a:

```
static AutoRegister< SomeClass<X1> > auto_X1;
static AutoRegister< SomeClass<X2> > auto_X2;
...
etc....
```

for each template class instantiation.

For FIW, I suspect there's no solution to this.

Comment: I think what you're talking about (and what many of the answers are) is called a "pluggable factory".

Comment: Well, perhaps not a pluggable factory per se, but a very similar idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can execute something before main once if a instantiation of a template is made. The trick is to put a static data member into a class template, and reference that from outside. The side effect that static data member triggers can be used to call the register function:

```
template<typename D>
struct automatic_register {
private:
    struct exec_register {
        exec_register() {
            persistenceSystem::registerPersistableType(
                D::getPersister()
            );
        }
    };
    // will force instantiation of definition of static member
    template<exec_register&> struct ref_it { };

    static exec_register register_object;
    static ref_it<register_object> referrer;
};

template<typename D> typename automatic_register<D>::exec_register 
    automatic_register<D>::register_object;
```

Derive the class you want to be auto-registered from `automatic_register<YourClass>` . The register function will be called before main, when the declaration of `referrer` is instantiated (which happens when that class is derived from, which will implicitly instantiate that class from the template).

Having some test program (instead of the register function, a function do_it is called):

```
struct foo : automatic_register<foo> {    
    static void do_it() {
        std::cout << " doit "; 
    } 
}; 

int main() { 
    std::cout << " main "; 
}
```

Yields this output (as expected):

```
doit main
```

Comment: Does this technique work in header files as well w/o violating the ODR? I also thought template statics like this lead to linker errors when used in headers included from multiple shared libraries? I admit I was using a simpler/naive static inside the template, and that I have a hard time to follow the above technique, but if this really works with headers / shared libraries, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why this works? So far I figured that instantiating `automatic_register` means registering the `ref_it` template (because a member of the `automatig_register` instantiation is of type `ref_it<register_object>`). Odd thing here is that you instantiate a template with a reference to some type, never saw that before. Anyway, instantiating `ref_it<register_object>` means that the static `register_object` member is used, which in turn means that the `exec_register` constructor is used, which in turn then calls the registration function. Did I get that right?

Comment: Johannes, your "doit main" example compiles fine, but outputs just " main" with Visual Studio 10 (SP1). We all know VS isn't exactly the most standard compliant compiler but would you have another solution that's more portable to VS and GCC and Clang?

Comment: Although this works when compiling and linking directly, gcc and clang both drop the call if you first put the object code containing foo's definition into an archive.  Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk because your main function does not use `foo` or anything else from the archive's .o file, so the linker drops that .o file. There's a linker option which instructs the linker to always use the whole archive file.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I'd like your (more of an expert) opinion regarding my suggestion below.

Answer (score 2):

Register each template at run-time in the constructor. Use a static variable per template to check if the type has already been registered. The following is a quickly hacked together example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Registerable {
    static vector<Registerable *> registry_;

public:
    static void registerFoo(Registerable *p)
    {
        registry_.push_back(p);
    }

    static void printAll()
    {
        for (vector<Registerable *>::iterator it = registry_.begin();
             it != registry_.end(); ++it)
            (*it)->print();
    }

    virtual void print() = 0;
};

vector<Registerable *> Registerable::registry_;

template <typename T>
class Foo : public Registerable {
    static bool registered_;

public:
    Foo()
    {
        if (!registered_) {
            registerFoo(this);
            registered_ = true;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << sizeof (T) << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T> bool Foo<T>::registered_ = false;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo<char> fooChar;
    Foo<short> fooShort;
    Foo<int> fooInt;

    Registerable::printAll();

    return 0;
}
```

It should output the size of each template parameter in the order the classes were instantiated:

```
1
2
4
```

---

This version removes the registration code from each constructor and puts it in a base class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Registerable {
    static vector<Registerable *> registry_;

public:
    static void registerFoo(Registerable *p)
    {
        registry_.push_back(p);
    }

    static void printAll()
    {
        for (vector<Registerable *>::iterator it = registry_.begin();
             it != registry_.end(); ++it)
            (*it)->print();
    }

    virtual void print() = 0;
};

vector<Registerable *> Registerable::registry_;

template <typename T>
class Registerer : public Registerable {
    static bool registered_;

public:
    Registerer(T *self)
    {
        if (!registered_) {
            registerFoo(self);
            registered_ = true;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T> bool Registerer<T>::registered_ = false;

template <typename T>
class Foo : public Registerer<Foo<T> > {
public:
    Foo() : Registerer<Foo<T> >(this) { }

    void print()
    {
        cout << sizeof (T) << endl;
    }
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo<char> fooChar;
    Foo<short> fooShort;
    Foo<int> fooInt;

    Registerable::printAll();

    return 0;
}
```

I added an example of another non-template class using the registry. So, the final output would be:

```
foo: 1
foo: 2
foo: 4
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The Registerable solution is a neat idea, but has a couple of issues.
Ideally, I'd like to not add code to the constructor:

1. Because it relies on calling the constructor in order to register the type, it's a 
   little haphazard about what gets registered and what doesn't.
   For things like persistence, I may never call the constructor of a particular type
   before using the list, but I may need the type's data in the list in order to 
   know how to un-persist an object in a file.
2. There's runtime cost during the constructor call. I'd like to front load the time cost 
   and not pay the cost many times. If I had a vector of these objects and resized the 
   vector I'd pay the time-cost each time the copy constructor was called.

Comment: The only additional copying overhead would be checking one conditional  to see if it has been registered, and you can get around that with proper copy constructors.

Answer (score 0):

### Use file-level static blocks to perform the different registrations

> A static block? What's that?

A static block is a block of code (i.e. code between curly braces, which defines a scope) that gets executed sometime before `main()` runs. Java [has this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java), and C++ has it too-

> [Whatch'a talkin' bout, Willis?](https://img.memesuper.com/7167e26fa81e5821d5e89cbd80eb4a2a_generators-d-and-memes-on-what-you-talkin-bout-willis-meme_510-383.jpeg) C++ don't have no static blocks!

No, really, C++ has static blocks. You just need to, uh, shall we say, ["expose" their existence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321324/1593077).

> Hmm. Curious. And how do the static blocks help my registration problem?

It's really very simple. Right after you define class `A`, you register it like so:

```
class A { /* ... whatever ... */ };

static_block {
    persistenceSystem::registerPersistableType(A::getPersister());
}
```

There is one caveat, though: static blocks can be a part of the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) together with any statically-initialized part of your persistence system; so you need to make sure it's ok for these static blocks to run before (most) other statics; and that it's ok for the different classes' Persister's to be registered in arbitrary order.