# Expression template code not optimized fully

Tags: c++, optimization, expression-templates

I have the following linear algebra function call (vector-vector addition) in C++.

```
int m = 4;

blasfeo_dvec one, two, three;

blasfeo_allocate_dvec(m, &one);
blasfeo_allocate_dvec(m, &two);
blasfeo_allocate_dvec(m, &three);

// initialize vectors ... (omitted)

blasfeo_daxpy(m, 1.0, &one, 0, &two, 0, &three, 0);
```

Using [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) (ETs), we can wrap it as follows:

```
three = one + two;
```

where the vector `struct` looks like

```
struct blasfeo_dvec {
    int m;          // length
    int pm;         // packed length
    double *pa;     // pointer to a pm array of doubles, the first is aligned to cache line size
    int memsize;    // size of needed memory

    void operator=(const vec_expression_sum<blasfeo_dvec, blasfeo_dvec> expr) {
        blasfeo_daxpy(m, 1.0, (blasfeo_dvec *) &expr.vec_a, 0, (blasfeo_dvec *) &expr.vec_b, 0, this, 0);
    }
};
```

The cast to non-`const` is necessary because `blasfeo_daxpy` takes non-`const` pointers. The ET code is simply

```
template<typename Ta, typename Tb>
struct vec_expression_sum {
    const Ta vec_a;
    const Tb vec_b;

    vec_expression_sum(const Ta va, const Tb vb) : vec_a {va}, vec_b {vb} {}
};

template<typename Ta, typename Tb>
auto operator+(const Ta a, const Tb b) {
    return vec_expression_sum<Ta, Tb>(a, b);
}
```

The 'native' call, i.e. `blasfeo_daxpy(...)` generates the following assembly:

```
; allocation and initialization omitted ...
movl    $0, (%rsp)
movl    $4, %edi
xorl    %edx, %edx
xorl    %r8d, %r8d
movsd   LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
movq    %r14, %rsi
movq    %rbx, %rcx
movq    %r15, %r9
callq   _blasfeo_daxpy
...
```

which is exactly what you would expect. The ET code is quite a bit longer:

```
; allocation :
leaq    -120(%rbp), %rbx
movl    $4, %edi
movq    %rbx, %rsi
callq   _blasfeo_allocate_dvec
leaq    -96(%rbp), %r15
movl    $4, %edi
movq    %r15, %rsi
callq   _blasfeo_allocate_dvec
leaq    -192(%rbp), %r14
movl    $4, %edi
movq    %r14, %rsi
callq   _blasfeo_allocate_dvec

; initialization code omitted    

; operator+ :
movq    -104(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -56(%rbp)
movq    -120(%rbp), %rax
movq    -112(%rbp), %rcx
movq    %rcx, -64(%rbp)
movq    %rax, -72(%rbp)

; vec_expression_sum : 
movq    -80(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -32(%rbp)
movq    -96(%rbp), %rax
movq    -88(%rbp), %rcx
movq    %rcx, -40(%rbp)
movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -128(%rbp)
movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -136(%rbp)
movq    -48(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -144(%rbp)
movq    -56(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -152(%rbp)
movq    -72(%rbp), %rax
movq    -64(%rbp), %rcx
movq    %rcx, -160(%rbp)
movq    %rax, -168(%rbp)
leaq    -144(%rbp), %rcx

; blasfeo_daxpy :
movl    -192(%rbp), %edi
movl    $0, (%rsp)
leaq    -168(%rbp), %rsi
xorl    %edx, %edx
xorl    %r8d, %r8d
movsd   LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
movq    %r14, %r9
callq   _blasfeo_daxpy
...
```

It involves quite a bit of copying, namely the fields of `blasfeo_dvec`. I (naively, maybe) hoped that the ET code would generate the exact same code as the native call, given that everything is fixed at compile time and `const`, but it doesn't.

**The question is: why the extra loads?** And is there a way of getting fully 'optimized' code? (edit: I use Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) with `-std=c++14 -O3`)

Note: I read and understood [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860798/expression-templates-are-not-being-inlined-fully) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111559/expression-template-implementation-not-being-optimized) post on a similar topic, but they unfortunately do not contain an answer to my question.

Comment: How are you compiling? What compiler, what version and what flags are you using? If you think there's a problem with your expression templates, it would be necessary to show them.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ is a useful online tool for exploring the different assembly output by different code, compilers or flags. It may be of use to you.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I use Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42), with flags `-std=c++14 -O3`