# Can an empty destructor cause harm?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to C++, and one of the concepts I'm working on understanding is destructors.  Out of curiosity, can an unnecessary (e.g., when a class has no dynamically allocated memory, resources, or anything requiring a user-defined destructor) and empty destructor cause any unforeseen problems?

**Edit:** I know that part of this has been answered in [Will an 'empty' constructor or destructor do the same thing as the generated one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025313/will-an-empty-destructor-do-the-same-thing-as-the-generated-destructor) but I wanted to broaden it to ask more about generalized negative consequences such as crashes or making an application slower. There is some overlap, but it is a slightly different question.

Comment: @mkaes It's a broader question than the one you refer to

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: The question itself can be interpreted as 'broader' but still the answer in the linked question answers this question too. So I still believe that this question should be closed.

Comment: @mkaes I was looking for more/slightly different information than was included in that question (which I had read).  Hopefully my edit clarifies a bit.

Comment: Well, an empty destructor can cause a memory leak, which would be bad. But I think you should make the question more precise, most answerers didn't read it this way. I guess you try to rule out "when a class has no dynamically allocated memory", but you should rule out "when a class has no resources". It might still leak files or sockets for instance if it owns "raw" C handles to those things and doesnt have a dtor.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Thanks for pointing that out, let me know if my most recent edit is still unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question depends on several parameters. Emptiness isn't the only thing that has effect on the result. E.g., if you don't define `virtual` destructor (empty or not), you'll get problematic behavior when inheriting from the class. On the other hand, if you define an empty destructor in `private` or `protected` section, it will prevent creating instances of the class on stack.

Comment: Problematic behavior doesn't come from **inheriting**, but from deleting though a pointer to the base type.

Comment: @PeteBecker True. I meant that deleting through a pointer to base is a very common and basic operation when working with polymorphic objects.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes, you are not likely to benefit from polymorphic objects unless you delete them through base at some point.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername - indeed; but base classes are not used exclusively for polymorphic types. For example, several base classes in the standard library do not have virtual destructors and do not need them.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes, the answer doesn't mention polymorphic objects! I did not see it. I agree with you, SWU should speficially mention those.

Comment: I agree with you both :)

Answer (score 5):

There is also an interesting aspect (which do not seem to be talked about in the linked duplicate) of a triviality of destructor. Compiler-generated (or `default`ed) destructors are considered *trivial* destructors, and having a trivial destructor is a pre-requisite of your class being a POD-type. The user-defined destructor, even if empty, prevents your class from being a POD-type.

And having a POD-type is sometimes very important. For example, POD-types can be `memcpy`ed or entity-serialized.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't dealt with memcpy yet but that is very helpful info.

Comment: @ce_nort - and you shouldn't deal with `memcpy` yet. Not for a long, long time.

Answer (score 1):

No, all members of the instance are still destroyed after your destructor ran. The only thing a destructor must not do is throwing an exception, otherwise it may do anything a "proper" method can do, i.e. also doing nothing at all is fine. Not closing handles when you should have is another question.

Answer (score 0):

No.  In fact, if you don't declare and write a destructor for a class or struct, the compiler will do it for you - and it will be empty.

Comment: Hmm.  I think a bald "Wrong" is a bit harsh.  If someone is getting to grips with what a "destructor" is, they aren't going to be worrying about POD types for some time.  (And I really can't think of a good reason to use memcpy over assignment/std::copy)

Comment: But there is a difference, so saying there is no difference is not correct. As for the benefits of `memcpy` (`std::copy` is not applicable here at all) as opposed to writing assignment operator is simply performance and code typing. And default assingment operator will call `memcpy` for PODs, instead of by member copying - again, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

"Empty destructor" is a bit of a misnomer.  Whether or not your destructor has a body, the compiler will still generate code to call the destructor of every non-static member variable and base class in reverse order of declaration.  You only need a body if you wish to do something before those other destructors get called.