# What is the Java `static {}` keyword all by itself?

Tags: java, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static Block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java)

I came across the following use of `static` and did not figure out what it does. 
I am aware of using for example `static String hello = "World";` but I do not understand the following.

```
static {
   loadFromProperties(new Properties());
}
```

Comment: The static block in the program is the first to execute when a VM is initialized. More specifically, the static block is used for initializing the static constants.

    public static final int MAX_ITER;
    static {
        int dummyMaxIter = AClass.calculateABC();
        if (dummyMaxIter >= 0) {
            MAX_ITER = dummyMaxIter;
        }
        else {
            MAX_ITER = 0;
        }
    }

See the above segment. can initialize the `MAX_ITER` directly from `AClass.calculateABC()`. But you need to validate the value returned by `AClass.calculateABC()` before assigning.

Comment: you are right, this is a duplicate. sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called a [static initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). It's a block of code that runs when the class is initialized.

Related question (probably a dup actually):

- [Static Block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java)

Comment: is initialization different to instantiation ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: *Class* initialization happens before any instances are created (instantiation).

Answer (score 3):

This is called static blocks. Those are executed when class is loaded/initialized but before instantiation. You can use then to initialize static members/fields.

Comment: Actually it's executed when the class is *initialized*. (In practice you seldom notice the difference though.)