# Checkstyle on class variable

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, checkstyle

Check style says that for a private class variable "must be declared final".

```
class Test {
    private int x=1;

    public void set(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

In the above case it calls to declare x as final however declaring x as final would give error on initializing it in the constructor. What's the catch?

Comment: What is the name of the check which raises the warning ?

Comment: a solution would have been more helpful....and this is just 4 lines of code...

Comment: @obourgain: field must be declared final

Comment: show us your full code.

Comment: why are you setting a static variable in an instance method???

Comment: hey guys x is not a static variable...Typo....mah badddd

Comment: Does the problem still exist? To my knowledge checkstyle shouldn't complain about hte above code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad style to make `private` and `static` field accessible for modifications through setter. You have to do one of the following things:

1) make field `x` `final` and remove `set` method for it.

either

2) make field `x` non-static (remove `static` keyword), then it will be not required to make it `final`.

Answer (score 0):

> however declaring x as final would give error on initializing it in the constructor

To initialize static fields use [static block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java).

And, why it should be `final` ... The reason is that

1. It is `private static` and can't be accessed from outside.
2. If it is not required to be `final` then no need to make it `static`

So, either remove `static` OR use `final private static`

Now, your other part of code:

```
public void set(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

Issues:

1. `static` fields should NOT be accessed using `this`.
2. Use static block to initialize static fields.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change the value of a static final field.

if you really need x to be static, change your method to

```
public static void setX(int newX){
    [...]
```

keep in mind, that in static methods "this" cannot be used.

this should solve your problem.