# Basic java regarding a code block

Tags: java, methods, static, accessor

I dont really know what to call this thing so sorry for the vague title, so basically I have an understanding of static fields and methods in a class but no idea what the usage of the following is and does:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public MyClass() 
     {

     }

     static 
     {

     }
}
```

someone care to explain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the static block:

```
static{

}
```

It gets executed before the main method; it is generally used to call other static methods and initialize static fields.

If you're referring to the constructor:

```
public MyClass(){

}
```

It used to *construct* an object when you create a new instance of it: `MyClass instance = new MyClass();`

Answer (score 1):

static initialization blocks are used to initialize a class's static fields after the class is loaded.

In your case, you are doing nothing inside that block, so it is actually useless.

Answer (score 1):

Its a static initialisation block. Which mean that the block is executed when the class is loaded, rather than when an instance is instantiated.

Useful for things like populating a map of values at class initialisation time.

Further information can be found in the [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks are called when the class is being loaded by the classloader (clinit bytecode section of the class)