# Hibernate auto generated class

Tags: java, hibernate

I found a the `HibernateUtil` class in my Package, it contains an unknown syntax  for me. I don't know what it is and how this works:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
//???
static {
    try{
        //Create the SessionFactory from standard config file (hibernate.cfg.xml)
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }catch (Throwable ex){
        //Log the Exception
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed: "+ ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
 }

 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

Comment: So what is ur question ?

Comment: That's vague. We can't start explaining ALL of that code. Try to ask one or more specific questions.

Comment: This class searches for `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in the classpath & once found it establishes a connection between database specified in config file & ur application. So that ur application have an access to DB & can perform  CRUD operation in DB.

Comment: the call     ´static{ }´  what is this? is java 8 or auto completion ?

Comment: This is static block in Java, it means no need to create an object of this class to create sessionFactory. The static code always executed first. U should learn basics of Java. We are not here to teach u from basic.

Comment: thanks static block was the keyword [static block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As it says, it is an utility class with a `static` block. 
This class make sure to have a session ready for your program. You would use this to get a handle on the session to work with your database.

A static block makes sure that it is run as the class loader loads the class into JVM. Here is more on JLS [Static Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is Hibernate SessionFactory singleton class. It create the SessionFactory object at the Class loading time. it read database properties from your Hibernate.cfg.xml file which is present in your src folder.

Whenever you want a SessionFactory object just call its instance method as shown below :

HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();