# How are object dependencies between static blocks resolved?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I recently came across this at work. While I am not sure it is really a good idea, I don't understand how static blocks are handled by the compiler.

Here is an example:

Consider that you have classes `A` and `B`:

```
public class A {

    public final static List<Integer> list;
    static {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class B {

    public final static int dependsOnA;
    static {
        dependsOnA = A.list.size();
    }
}
```

And a main class that just reads `B.dependsOnA`.

The static block in `B` is dependent of the one in `A`, since it uses the `list` static variable.

Now, the code executes properly and no `NullPointerException` is raised at runtime. But what is the mechanism that ensures that `list` is initialized before it is potentially used elsewhere?

Comment: From a *design* point-of-view, I cordially suggest that it's not a good idea for class `A` to make *public* its `list` property, in the first place.  Instead, I would have made it private, and provided *methods* in `A` which give all other classes "the things they need to know, and the ability to do the things that they need to do."  A very important benefit is that, now, class `A` is both self-contained and self-describing.  All of the code needed to ensure that class `A` is working correctly, is *in* class `A`, whose code is protected from interference or side-effects (like `B`).

Comment: ... also:  "What can `A` do, and what can others do to `A`?"  This question can now be answered, definitively, by looking *only* at `A`.  The runtime difference between the two is negligible, but the design, IMHO, is much more robust and debuggable.  (And, much less dependent upon "exactly when Java does this-or-that.")  I submit that it's a good principle to say:  "do not let other classes meddle in the affairs of other classes."  Much as it is wise for humans ("who are crunchy, and taste good with Fava beans ...") not to meddle with dragons.

Comment: if list is already static wouldnt A.list.size() direct access be more efficient ?

Comment: @MikeRobinson The code in question will depend on when Java does this -or-that even if A.list was private.  (Assuming you expose a method to add items to the list, and a method for getting the size of the array).  Semantically the order java does this means that `B.dependsOnA` holds the number of items in A that was present the first time B was accessed.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh It would not do the same thing.  See my comment to Mike.

Comment: Yes, and what I'm suggesting here is that "the `dependsOn` aspect of it" is what smells really bad to me.  I would want to (re-)design the class structure such that no such dependencies existed, or needed to exist.  Let each class be the master of its own kingdom.  Now, I'm not saying that you can actually *do* that, in any deployed production application, but to my way of thinking, "what was done, here," is not a particularly good thing to have done.

Comment: *code executes properly and no NullPointerException is raised at runtime.* => in static block of class A you got *list = new ArrayList<>();* , **so there will never be a NPE exception**

Comment: @MikeRobinson That doesn't change anything in this question though. The list would still be created in A's static initializer, and B would still call `getList` to get it, and there would still be some mechanism to ensure that A's static initializer runs before the list is needed.

Comment: ... unless `getList` used a "lazy initialization" technique, initializing the list (if necessary) the first time it's called to get the list.  Lots and lots of ways to do this.  And, in production apps, limited options for "changing it now."

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Never say never. If you look at my answer, you can easily see how even a `public static final List<> X = new ArrayList<>();` field can be observed to be null from the initialiser of another class.

Answer (score 34):

The mechanism is described in detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), but the five most important points are:

1. Before a class is referenced, it needs to be initialised.
2. If initialisation of a class has already begun (or if it's finished), it isn't attempted again.
3. Before a class is initialised, all its superclasses and superinterfaces need to be initialised first.
4. Static initialisers within a single class are executed in textual order.
5. Implemented interfaces are initialised in the order in which they appear in the `implements` clause.

These rules completely define the order in which static blocks are executed.

Your case is rather simple: before you access `B.dependsOnA`, `B` needs to be initialised (rule 1), the static initialiser is then trying to access `A.list`, which triggers the initialisation of class `A` (again rule 1).

Note that there's nothing stopping you from creating circular dependencies this way, which will cause interesting things to happen:

```
public class Bar {
    public static int X = Foo.X+1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( Bar.X+" "+Foo.X); // 
    }

}

class Foo {
    public static int X = Bar.X+1;
}
```

The result here is `2 1` because the way the initialisation happens is this:

1. `Bar`s initialisation begins.
2. `Bar.X`s initial value is evaluated, which requires initialising `Foo` first
3. `Foo`s initialisation begins.
4. `Foo.X`s initial value is evaluated, but since `Bar`s initialisation is already in progress, it isn't initialised again, `Bar.X`s "current" value is used, which is 0, thus `Foo.X` is initialised to 1.
5. We're back to evaluating `Bar.X`s value, `Foo.X` is 1 so `Bar.X` becomes 2.

This works even if both fields were declared `final`.

The moral of the story is to be careful with static initialisers referring to other classes in the same library or application (referring to classes in a third party library or standard class library is safe as they won't be referring back to your class).

Answer (score 9):

The "mechanism" is the JVM's classloader, which will ensure that a class' initalization blocks are executed (with a global lock across the whole JVM) before returning control flow to where the class was first referenced. It will first load class `A` only after referenced, in this case when `B`'s init block references `A.list`.

Answer (score 8):

During execution of the `static` block of `B`, the runtime encounters `A` for the first time, and it will invoke the `static` block of `A` before it accesses `A.list`.

Comment: The term `static` blocks is more common than `static` constructor. Not sure if anyone actually uses this term.

Comment: Thanks Chetan, I changed it now. I use a lot of other languages (e.g. C#) where it's called a static constructor.

Answer (score 7):

No matter how you write the code, a `static` block is a `static` block and it will execute as part of the JVM loading a class.

When you say `B.dependsOnA`, `B` class starts geting loaded by the JVM and the `static` block in `B` gets called somewhere during this process. When you say `dependsOnA = A.list.size();`, class `A` starts getting loaded by the JVM and the `static` block in A will execute somewhere during this process which initializes the `list`. The statment `list.size()` will only execute after class `A` has been loaded completely by the JVM. Subsequently, the JVM can only finish loading class `B`  after the static block in B completes.

Answer (score 6):

This is the job of the class loader. The class loading in java starts with the **bootstrap** classloader. This class loader first loads all the classes in the standard java library, the **rt.jar**.

Then the **extension** classloader is invoked. This loads all the classes from the extension jar files installed in a JVM ext directory. Now finally the classpath classloader is invoked.

The classpath classloader starts loading classes from the main class, the class that has the main method defined. Once it is loaded, it executes any **static** initializers in that class. While in the execution of the initializer, if it encounters any class that is not loaded, it will pause the execution of the static block, loads the class first, and finally resumes the execution of that static block.

So, there is no chance that any calls to non-loaded classes to occur. Let's see this with your own example, whose code is like this:

```
class A
{
    public final static List<Integer> list;
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Loaded Class A");
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

class B
{
    public final static int dependsOnA;
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Loaded Class B");
        dependsOnA = A.list.size();
    }
}
```

Here in this example, there is actually no main method, so these classes won't actually be loaded into the memory. Suppose, let's add the following main class to the above code.

```
class C
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Loaded Class C");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(B.dependsOnA);
    }
}
```

Let's see what this would produce in the output: http://ideone.com/pLg3Uh

```
Loaded Class C
Loaded Class B
Loaded Class A
0
```

That is, first the class C is loaded, because it had the main method. Once it is loaded, the static initializer of class C is invoked. Notice, however, that the main method is invoked after the static block of class C is loaded.

Now the main method, we printed the value of `dependsOnA` of class B. Now, the class loader stops executing that statement, and loads the class B, and executes it's static block, which in turn, assigns the `dependsOnA` variable with the value of the number of elements in the list of class A, which is not loaded.

So the class loader jumps from there, loads the class now, and invokes the static block of the class A, and a list is created. Now since there are no more classes to load, the class loader comes back to the static block of class B, and assignment is complete. Now finally, the control is now with the main method, and the value of `dependsOnA` is printed to the console.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here we have some explaination
[Static Block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java)

If you call the A class first, the A static is called and A.list exists and will when B will call it.

If you call the B class first, the B static is called, cascading to the A call, calling its static block, where A.list is created.

We could see is its trickiest way:
B > B.static > A > A.static > A.list exists

Answer (score 5):

**The working is very simple JVM class loader, which will ensure that a class static blocks are executed when the class is first referenced.**
1.If you have executable statements in the static block, JVM will automatically execute these statements when the class is loaded into JVM.
2.If you’re referring some static variables/methods from the static blocks, these statements will be executed after the class is loaded into JVM same as above i.e., now the static variables/methods referred and the static block both will be executed.