# Static field initializer is being invoked after static method execution

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-members, jls

I've got a class with only static members, designed like that:

```
public class Clazz {

    public static final Foo foo = FooFactory.createFoo();

    private static Bar bar;

    public static void prepare() {
        bar = new Bar(foo);
    }
}
```

When calling Clazz.prepare(), I can see that foo is null at bar initializing. As far as I know, static initializer should be invoked just before the invocation of any static method of the class. Therefore, foo should already be initialized when prepare() is called.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `FooFactory.createFoo()` do?

Comment: `FooFactory.createFoo()` must be returning a `null` value

Comment: Basically, it does return new Foo();

Comment: It doesn't return a null value. More that that, after prepare() has finished, foo is actually initialized, just **after** the method invocation.

Comment: @basme Basically is not good enough, [class initialisation can be tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192250/how-are-object-dependencies-between-static-blocks-resolved/30192463#30192463). Can you please post a full code example that exhibits the odd behaviour?

Comment: @basme Then the question is: where do you call `Clazz.prepare()` from.

Comment: Please add the code of `Bar` class and `FooFactory` class

Answer (score 1):

`FooFactory.createFoo()` must be returning a `null` value

Comment: Which can also be caused by the value returned depending on `Clazz.foo`.

Comment: An alternative problem is if `Clazz.prepare()` is called from the class initialiser of `Foo`, `FooFactory`, or `Bar`.

Comment: @biziclop yes indeed but we must see FooFactory to tell.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, initializer of Foo calls Clazz.prepare() too. That's the reason. Thanks @biziclop for the idea.