# Accessing static object without creating an instance of the class containing it

Tags: java

I'm having problem understanding "`static`". I have created class "`pizzaMenu`" containing ArrayList which contains pizzas. All pizzas are added within that class, and it shouldn't be modified later. But I want to access data about pizzas.

Everything is working properly, but I have to create object of "`pizzaMenu`" in "`main`" to make it work.

How can I properly initiate such instances, so I have access to them? But the initiation won't be visible in "`main`"? I'd like to keep "`main`" as clean as possible.

Comment: Some code examples would be helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for [static initialization blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2943556)?

Comment: It is a good idea to keep method code clean, but it is not a good idea to keep it so clean that you have to add any global variables.

Comment: Yes, eckes . I missed the concept. Thank you all for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I have to create object of "pizzaMenu" in "main" to make it work.

Yes, you need *an instance* of `new PizzaMenu()` in order to access that menu's items.

> I'm having problem understanding "static".

Nothing in `PizzaMenu` should really be `static` (other than `main`, if you have it there). But, it basically mean it belongs to the class, and not *any one instance* of that class.

In other words, if you did make the list of pizzas `static`, then that says that *all menus have the same pizzas*, which shouldn't be true, right? Different places have different menus.

Here's an example.

```
public class PizzaMenu {

    private List<String> pizzas = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String name) {
        pizzas.add(name);
    }

    public List<String> getPizzas() {
        return pizzas;
    }

    // You can also move this to another class
    public static void main() {
        PizzaMenu menu = new PizzaMenu();
        menu.add("Cheese");

        for (String pizza : menu.getPizzas()) {
            System.out.println(pizza);
        }
    }
}
```

> All pizzas are added within that class, and it shouldn't be modified later.

You can use this, for example

```
private final List<String> pizzas = Arrays.asList("Cheese", "Pepperoni");
```

But, again, I think different instances of menus should have different pizzas.

Comment: In your example with `final`, `pizzas` is still mutable. You should use `Collections.unmodifiableList()` to make the List immutable (since it shouldn't be modified later).

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm just looking for problem where there is none. I just wanted to remove: PizzaMenu menu = new PizzaMenu(); from the "main". To keep "main" clear. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Polygnome You can't add/remove from `Arrays.asList`, but yes, you can update the elements directly.

Comment: @karjan You **can** move `PizzaMenu menu = new PizzaMenu()` outside of main. Then, it becomes a member variable of the outer class, **but**, then it **must** be `static`

Comment: Its not about adding/removing. `Arrays.asList()` is only fixed in size with changes written through to the backing array. `pizzas.set(0, "Not a pizza");` is a perfectly valid call that writes through in your example. Thus, to truly fulfil the requirment of "should not be modified later" the list should be wrapped into an immutable read-only wrapper.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes cricket that was my first idea. But to access PizzaMenu menu = new PizzaMenu() outside of main. I still hava to make an instance of the class containing it, inside main. I'm right?

Comment: @karjan I don't think so... If you make a `static` instance of a `PizzaMenu` outside of `main`, then you can also use that same instance across other methods of the same class without a new one

Comment: But then, making `PizzaMenu` static is almost certainly wrong. Global state is bad. Why don't you want to declare an instance, exactly, @karjan? I don't see a valid engineering reason in anything you've said so far.

Comment: @LewBloch I thought it's unnecessary. I see that I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can declare pizzas as public static within pizzamenu.

```
public final static List<pizza> pizzas;
```

So you can access the pizza using

```
PizzaMenu.pizzas.
```

Also you mentioned

> I'd like to keep "main" as clean as possible.

I think your concept about `clean code` is not fully correct.

Comment: Don't make `pizzas` static.