# Curly braces only method

Tags: java, curly-braces, order-of-execution

Why does Java accept a *brackets only* method? What is made for?

```
{
    // Do something
}
```

I also noticed that it is executed automatically after the [*static-block*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java) but before the constructor. Although the constructor of the *super class* is executed before.

Is there a specific reason for this order?

This is the [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) I made for discovering the execution order:

```
public class TestClass extends TestSuperClass {

    public TestClass() {
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("brackets");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("static");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestSuperClass {

    public TestSuperClass() {
        System.out.println("super class constructor");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("super class brackets");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("super class static");
    }
}
```

As output I get:

```
super class static
static
super class brackets
super class constructor
brackets
constructor
test
```

Comment: *"Is there a specific reason for this order?"*  -  It is explained in JLS 15.9.4 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as static block but just not static. So it will execute in the order that you already found out - after super constructor but before constructor. However, if static-block can be useful regular block not so much. So it is never used, but it is legal. I never saw it used and can not think of any particular purpose, but it is part of valid syntax. If it was not then static block wouldn't be either.

Comment: I've actually seen it used once : in a very long method creating UI components, it was used to limit scope of local variables. It's the half-baked way of extracting code in another method. A bad practice IMO.

Comment: Sure, I agree Jeremy, bad practice in IMHO as well. Just proves my point that it is never used and when it is - it shouldn't have been