# Taking a data set and printing it in a 2D array

Tags: java

so I have written the code to a program that should initialize a data set of totals from different locations and display them as such. for some reason I keep getting a run time error on the first for-loop and can't figure out why. can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Sales {

private static String[] months;
private static String[] cities;
private static int[] citySum;
private static int[] monthlySum;
private static int[][] sales;
private static int col;
private static int row;


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    calCityTotal();
    calMonthlyTotal();
    displayTable();

}

public Sales() {

    months = new String[] {"January","Febuary","March","April",
                           "May","June"};

    cities = new String[] {"Chilliwack","Kamloops","Kelowna",
                           "NanaimoSurrey","Vancouver","Victoria"};

    sales = new int[][] {{400,500,500,600,500,600},
                        {600,800,800,800,900,900},
                        {700,700,700,900,900,1000},
                        {500,600,700,800,700,700},
                        {900,900,900,1000,1100,1100}};

    citySum = new int[sales.length];

    monthlySum = new int[sales[0].length];
}

public static void calCityTotal() {

    for (row = 0; row < sales.length; row++){
        for (col = 0; col < sales[0].length; col++){
            citySum[col] += sales[row][col];
        }
    }
}

public static void calMonthlyTotal() {

    for (row = 0; row < sales.length; row++){
        for (col = 0; col < sales[0].length; col++){
            monthlySum[row] += sales[row][col];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, where is the method `displayTable()` in your code?

Comment: I haven't finished writing the displayTable() method yet so I didn't include it but I am getting: 

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sales.Sales.calCityTotal(Sales.java:57)
 at sales.Sales.main(Sales.java:30)
/Users/jordan/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Now which is line 57?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your current code:

1) Variables are not getting initialized. For that, you can create `Sales` object in `main` method(remove static keyword from `calCityTotal` and `calMonthlyTotal`).

2) Once above problem is resolved, you will encounter `Arrayindexoutofboundsexception` because `citySum` has length of `sales.length` whereas your loop in `calCityTotal` goes to `sales[0].length`.

It doesn't make sense to declare variables as `static` and initialize them in `constructor`. Static variables should be independent of any instances.
Go through [Java: when to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods) to know when to declare static variables. If you want to declare variables as `static`, you should initialize them in `static` block([Static Block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java)).

Below code will work:

```
public class Sales {

private String[] months;
private String[] cities;
private int[] citySum;
private int[] monthlySum;
private int[][] sales;
private int col;
private int row;


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sales salesObj = new Sales();
    salesObj.calCityTotal();
    salesObj.calMonthlyTotal();

}

public Sales() {


    months = new String[]{"January", "Febuary", "March", "April",
            "May", "June"};

    cities = new String[]{"Chilliwack", "Kamloops", "Kelowna",
            "NanaimoSurrey", "Vancouver", "Victoria"};

    sales = new int[][]{{400, 500, 500, 600, 500, 600},
            {600, 800, 800, 800, 900, 900},
            {700, 700, 700, 900, 900, 1000},
            {500, 600, 700, 800, 700, 700},
            {900, 900, 900, 1000, 1100, 1100}};

    citySum = new int[sales.length+1];

    monthlySum = new int[sales[0].length];
}

public void calCityTotal() {

    for (row = 0; row < sales.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < sales[0].length; col++) {
            citySum[col] += sales[row][col];
        }
    }
}

public void calMonthlyTotal() {

    for (row = 0; row < sales.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < sales[0].length; col++) {
            monthlySum[row] += sales[row][col];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thank you that helped a lot! do you have any advice on how I would print this with the cities on the left data in the middle city totals on the right and monthly totals underneath?

Comment: You can use for loop to print it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `NullPointerException` because `sales` is `null` at line `for (row = 0; row < sales.length; row++)`.

Even though you set a value to `sales` variable in the constructor `Sales()`, you are never calling that constructor (like `new Sales()`).

So, to fix this `NullPointerException` you can call the `Sales` constructor in the `main()` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  new Sales();

  calCityTotal();
  calMonthlyTotal();
  displayTable();
}
```

**EDIT**
After fixing the `NullPointerException`, your code still has few other problems.

Inside `calCityTotal()`, `sales[0].length` should be corrected as `sales[row].length` I think.

`citySum` array is initialized to the length of `sales`. This means `citySum.length` is equal to the number of "rows". But then you write `citySum[col]` which can lead to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because number of "columns" can exceeds `citySum.length`. (This actually happens in your program. Because number of row = 5 and number of columns = 6.)