# Constructor in the Try/Catch block

Tags: java

The question is about the result of the below code. The answer is compilation error. However I really do not understand why we can't have constructor in try/catch block. I will put the the code below:

```java
public class Test {
    try {
        public Test() {
            System.out.println("GeeksforGeeks");
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("GFG");
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Test test= new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you can have a wallet inside your pocket, not a pocket inside a wallet.

Comment: Does that actually come from GeeksForGeeks?

Comment: The classes body is not runnable (except static blocks) so it doesn't make sense to allow code that will run to be put there. The try/catch needs to go where the constructor is called i.e. the main function.

Comment: I came across on facebook but I do not know exact source @Aniox

Comment: @Paul Rooney how can I make it static blocks?

Comment: You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java) but why do you want to? You still wont be able to define the constructor in a static block.

Comment: so I know I can write try/catch in main. I am just curious about the different way. For instance, can I put try/catch inside the static block? What is the downside of it?

Comment: You're trying to put java code directly inside a class definition without putting it inside a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a constructor is a declaration, not a statement.

Your constructor *can be called* by other code, but merely declaring it does not execute it;  that’s what `new Test()` does.  Nothing is executed merely by declaring the constructor, so there is nothing that can throw an exception.  Thus, there is nothing to catch.

In more general syntax terms, statements which don’t evaluate to a value can only exist in constructors, methods, and initialization blocks.

You can, however, do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Test test = new Test();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

`new Test()` actually *executes* the constructor, which is why it may throw an exception and thus you can legally attempt to catch any exception it may throw.  Syntactically, all of the above code is inside a method (the `main` method), which is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

**Because the assignments are statements and statements are allowed only inside blocks of code(methods, constructors, static initializers, etc.)**
here's the clean code

```
public class Test {

    public Test()throws Exception {
        System.out.println("GeeksforGeeks");
        throw new Exception();
    }



public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        Test test= new Test();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I didn't downvote but the question was: `why we can't have constructor in try/catch block`

Comment: Not well explained. Can you be more clear? @ElMobark

Comment: ah sorry my bad - fix it :D