# Why @PostConstruct is not working in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code in the spring boot application:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationLists {
    
    private List<Country> countryItems = new ArrayList<Country>();

@PostConstruct
    protected void init() {     
        initCountryList();
```

And the @PostConstruct method is called only when I submit a request through postman, I need
this code to run om startup.
Thanks,

Comment: Maybe the `ServletContext` is initialized during the first request and so does a bean with application scope? I don't know... But, given your code, maybe you could also use a [static initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943580/344480)?

Comment: Have a look in the answer and comment if you like,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of @PostConstruct I'm implementing ApplicationRunner, it has
run method. That's solve the problem, I just hope that
this is the right thing to do in spring boot.