# Templated Automatic Factory Registration

Tags: c++, c++17

Imagine I had some objects that were all related to some interface class base.  However, all of these objects are templated by some integer `DIM` (dimension).  I have assumed all derivatives of base have a static member `int number()` and a static string `InputName`.  The idea is to register this static method number().  (Really each class will have whole static interface.)

Registration.hpp

```cpp
template <int DIM>
class objectRegistry
{
  public:
    template<typename T>
    Register() 
   {
      //something like interface_map[T::InputName] = T::number;
   }
  private:
    static inline std::map<std::string, std::function<int ()>> interface_map;
}
```

Header1.hpp

```cpp
template <int DIM>
class base
{
  public:
    static inline const std::string InputName = "base";
    static int number() { return 1; };
    base(){};
};
//todo: Some Registration Here
```

Header2.hpp

```cpp
template <int DIM>
class derived : public base<DIM>, public AutomaticRegister<DIM, derived<DIM>>
{
  public:
    static inline std::string InputName = "derived";
    static int number() { return 4; };
    derived(){};
};

//todo: Some Registration Here
```

hearder3.hpp

```cpp
template <int DIM, typename extra_type>
class derived2 : public base<DIM>, public AutomaticRegister<DIM, derived2<DIM,extra_type>>
{
  public:
    static inline std::string InputName  = "derived2 " + std::string(typeid(extra_type).name());
    static int number() { return 5; };

    extra_type member;
};

//todo: Some Registration Here
```

Can I create an automatic registration system for derived objects (all derived from base); ideally, one that exists in the same header file as the object definition.  I would like, for example, objectRegistry<3> to know that derived<3>, derived2<3,int>, and derived<3,double> exist.  I have tried these methods:

[Best way to for C++ types to self register in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401621/best-way-to-for-c-types-to-self-register-in-a-list)
https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/02/factory-selfregister.html

However, because everything is buried in the `template< int DIM>`, it is never instantiated.

Is there a way I can force `derived` to instantiated when `objectRegistry` is instantiated with a particular template value?

Comment: Can you shorten it down to focus on one detail in all this? Try to make a [mcve].

Comment: I buried all the code I tried in some links.

Answer (score 1):

Either of the two approaches you linked to will work.

Your problem is that you are using class templates, not classes.

If you did this

```cpp
class Something : public AutomaticRegister<Something>
{
    // ...
};
```

then you would get automatic registry, because `Something` is a class.

You have class templates, which are not anything like a type at all.
The registration happens by instantiating the registration class, which is a base class of your class template.

So, in order to instantiate the registration class, you need the stuff you want registered to be treated as a type.  Thus, you need to instantiate some part of the class, either by creating an instance of one of the templates...

```cpp
derived2<1, double> d2_1_double;
```

or by explicitly instantiating the entire class template...

```cpp
template class derived2<1, double>;
```

or by explicitly instantiating some member of the class template, like the number function...

```cpp
template int derived2<1, double>::number();
```

or by creating an actual derived class...

```cpp
struct d2_1_double : derived2<1, double> { };
```

or some other way to stamp out a class from a class template.

However, a very minor change to the registration class template (adding a type member alias) gives us a mechanism to register them explicitly in bulk, and does not require inheriting from the registration mechanism.

To demonstrate, I added a bit of extremely simple non-production-quality code.  To do so, I added a non-standard function to get a unique name for a type that will work for gcc and clang, but no idea about other compilers.  It is not necessary, just makes it easier for me.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename ... Ts> struct TypeList { };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto
fname()
{
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

class Registry
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::function<int()>> map;

public:
    void insert(std::string_view key, std::function<int()> value) {
        assert(map.find(key) == map.end());
        std::cout << "Register \"" << key << "\", " << value() << '\n';
        map[key] = std::move(value);
    }
    int operator()(std::string_view key) const {
        return map.at(key)();
    }
};

template <int DIM>
Registry & registry()
{
    static Registry result;
    return result;
}
```

And here is the stuff to do the auto-registration, a modified version of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/401801/508595) from one of your links.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class AutoRegister
{
    struct helper {
        helper() { registry<T::dim>().insert(fname<T>(), T::number); }
    };
    /* inline */ static helper h;
    template<helper&> struct ref { using type = AutoRegister; };
public:
    using type = typename ref<h>::type;
};
// NOTE: A bug in gcc forces this usage rather than just using inline.
template <typename T>
typename AutoRegister<T>::helper AutoRegister<T>::h;
```

Then, with some class templates similar to yours...

```cpp
template <int DIM>
struct Bar
{
    static constexpr int dim = DIM;
    static int number() { return dim*100 + 99; }
};
template <int DIM, typename T>
struct Baz
{
    static constexpr int dim = DIM;
    static int number() { return dim*100 + 86; }
};
template <int DIM, typename ... Ts>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int dim = DIM;
    static int number() { return dim*100 + 42; }
};
```

and a helper alias template...

```cpp
template <typename ... Ts>
using RegisterTypes = TypeList<typename AutoRegister<Ts>::type...>;
```

We can register the stuff we want.  The second one has some duplicates just to show that stuff gets registered once.

```cpp
using Registered = RegisterTypes<Bar<0>, Bar<1>, Baz<1>, Foo<1>>;
using Registered2 = RegisterTypes<Bar<2>, Bar<1>, Baz<1>, Foo<1>>;

int main()
{
}
```

Running the program results in the following output...

````
Register "auto fname() [T = Bar<0>]", 99
Register "auto fname() [T = Bar<1>]", 199
Register "auto fname() [T = Baz<1, int>]", 186
Register "auto fname() [T = Foo<1, int>]", 142
Register "auto fname() [T = Bar<2>]", 299
Register "auto fname() [T = Foo<1, int, double>]", 142```
````

Comment: Thanks for this.  Escaping the inherited registration object is really nice.

Comment: So, ideally I would do something like: ```template<int DIM> using Registerd = RegisteredTypes<Bar<DIM>,Baz<DIM>>``` etc... and instantiate that.  which is fine.  The issue is that we've seemed to have lost the automatic registration part.  If I don't include the header that ```Bar``` is declared in, nothing compiles.  (This is all part of a library that I hoped would be quasi modular.)

Comment: Create one file as part of the library that does the registration.